# mongoDB won't stop with shutdown or kill

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongodb fork and running with high CPU usage. I'm trying to shut it down but nothing seems to work.

```
 2729 mwon      20   0 10.080g 9.047g  22668 S  56.2 28.8   4254:11 mongod --dbpath /disk2/db --port 27018 -logpath /disk2/db/mongod.log --fork
```

I have tried:

```
mongod --dbpath /disk2/db --shutdown
```

but it hangs without any kind of response. I also tried:

```
 kill 2729
 kill -2 2729
```

The command gets executed but nothing happens. This is the `tail` of the log:

```
2019-07-30T15:55:27.757+0000 I NETWORK  [conn13356] end connection 127.0.0.1:45690 (62 connections now open)
2019-07-30T15:55:27.758+0000 I NETWORK  [conn13368] end connection 127.0.0.1:45764 (61 connections now open)
2019-07-30T15:55:27.759+0000 I NETWORK  [conn13380] end connection 127.0.0.1:45826 (60 connections now open)
2019-07-30T15:55:27.764+0000 I NETWORK  [conn13381] end connection 127.0.0.1:45832 (59 connections now open)
2019-07-30T15:55:27.764+0000 I NETWORK  [conn13369] end connection 127.0.0.1:45772 (58 connections now open)
2019-07-30T15:55:27.765+0000 I NETWORK  [conn13344] end connection 127.0.0.1:45628 (57 connections now open)
2019-07-30T15:59:17.043+0000 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] got signal 15 (Terminated), will terminate after current cmd ends
2019-07-30T15:59:17.044+0000 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2019-07-30T15:59:17.044+0000 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27018.sock
2019-07-30T16:23:37.773+0000 I NETWORK  [conn11035] end connection 127.0.0.1:48928 (56 connections now open)
```

Comment: kill -2 is the graceful way to shut it down. Can you try `use admin` and then `db.shutdownServer()`

Comment: I'm also not able to start the shell. When I type `mongo --port 27018` it hangs waiting for a connection.

Comment: @AmbianBeing, do you know what is the meaning of `will terminate after current cmd ends`?

Comment: From what i understand that is just the `SIGTERM (signal 15)` received by the process. And it is the expected output when you kill a process.

Comment: @Miguel that means it's busy processing a work that cannot be interrupted, and will shutdown once it's done. It's best to wait for it to shutdown cleanly. Interrupting it at this point could lead to data loss.